# Join with another table containing tags

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called "posts" with the following struture:

```
post_id  |  post_body  | post_posterid
```

And I have another table called "tags":

```
tag_id  |  tag_name
```

A third table stores the relation between the two tables (will have multiple tags_id for each post_id as separate records):

```
post_id  |  tag_id
```

This is similar to stackoverflow's tagging that i am trying to create.

But I do not know how to join the tables and to concatenate tags for each post, in a single record. Like this:

```
post_id  |  post_body  |  post_postername  |  tag_id1  |  tag_id2  |  tag_id3  ..... tag_name1  |  tag_name2  | tag_name3 ....
```

So while fetching from mysql using PDO, I can avoid further queries to get tag names.

**EDIT**
More details:

First table("posts") contains post id(a unique id), posted message and poster's id(unique poster id which is stored in table "poster").
Second table "tags" contains possible tags(like "php", "vb.net", etc. like in stackoverflow) with unique tag_id.
Third table contains the relation between posted message and tags. So it contains post_id and its corresponding tag_id. It is possible to have more than 1 tag assigned to same post.

What i want: when queried, i can join "posts" with "posters" table to get name. But i want to get tags for each posts also.

GROUP_CONCAT() is answer for my question. But how to obtain it as tag_id - tag_name pair, instead of all tag_id in a field and all tag_name in another.

Eg: `1-VB , 5-PHP , 19-SQL`

I will separate this pairs in PHP

What i am trying is same as stackoverflow's tagging system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

keyword is `GROUP_CONCAT`

and query is like

```
SELECT 
posts.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name) tags
FROM
posts
LEFT JOIN relation ON relation.post_id  = posts.id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = relation.tag_id
GROUP BY posts.id
```

hope this help

Comment: thank you Tufan. So i should group_concat both tag_id and tag_name as separate fields and at PHP, split it and output it. Correct ?

Comment: how do we get it as tag_id - tag_name pair instead of id and name in separate field ?

Comment: change GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name)  to GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(tags.tag_id,'-',tags.tag_name))

Comment: ok. But when i executed the query (not the same query that you posted), it shows a _"Unknown Table Status: TABLE_TYPE"_ error. But it is successfully showing resultset.

Comment: if you executed the query on phpmyadmin, please update your phpyadmin script to the latest version. it is not the errormsg of this query.

Comment: yes. I executed in phpmyadmin to verify it. I am using WAMP server. So this phpmyadmin version is 3.3.9